# validating excel file upload

Tags: c#, javascript, excel, file-upload

Please help me in validating excel file upload. I have done coding for uploadation of excel file, and i want to validate whether the file is really a excel or not . I have also checked by renaming an x.exe file like x.exe.xls also by placing server side checking as given bellow but it failed. My requirement is to upload only valid excel file and not any other file like .exe, .dll or exe file tampered as x.exe.xls etc as said before.

```
if (fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||

  fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/excel" ||  

  fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-msexcel" ||

 fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" //this is xlsx format )
```

Comment: Identify the file by reading the first few bytes and checking for magic bytes that are common to all of these file types.

Answer (score 0):

Something I used before:

```
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    public bool ValidateExcelFile(string fileName)
    {
        string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\"", fileName);
        OleDbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If the file is not of actual Excel format, this will return false.

Answer (score -1):

As Ray said, you'll have to check the magic bytes of the uploaded file.
But this is going to cost a lot (computation time)

So I advise to first check that the file name and the ContentType are correct

Please note that this will NOT allow you to reject files that would have been modified in the middle of the file (keeping the magic bytes intact...).

Comment: Reading the first few bytes of a file shouldn't be very costly at all.

Comment: @RayNicholus : You're right, but if you already know that the file doesn't match the others requierments (right file extention), it's no use to use CPU time for this...